# PowerShell script to move files with date as name in it to a folder

Tags: powershell

I did some basic scripts in the past with powershell but now I'm stuck.

We have users that place PDF files with specific date in the filename:

```
TSE_M001340_04-Nov-2015_bis_03-Nov-2018.pdf
```

What I try to accomplish: 
look for the date after "bis_" (in this example "03-Nov-2018") and if it is  before (so younger) compared to the actual date move it to another folder.

What I tried so far:

```cs
$a = dir c:\temp\test
$a | foreach {
    $file = $_.Name;
    $full = $_.FullName

    switch -wildcard ($file) {
        "*bis_*" {
            $file
            [string]$date = ($file.Split("_"))[2]
            $date
            $datetime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($date, "yyyyMMdd", $null)
            $datetime
            if ($datetime -lt (Get-Date)) {
                Move-Item $full "C:\temp\test\copy\"
            }
        }
    } #end switch
} #end foreach
```

Error:

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

Any thoughts?

@Florian:
still getting the error and all files are copied. 
this is the output of the variables:

```
PS C:\Temp\test> $split
bis_

PS C:\Temp\test> $File
TSE_M001340_Dolder AG_04-Nov-2015_bis_03-Nov-2018

PS C:\Temp\test> $date
M001340

PS C:\Temp\test> 
PS C:\Temp\test> 
PS C:\Temp\test> $datetime

PS C:\Temp\test> 
PS C:\Temp\test> $full
C:\temp\test\TSE_M001340_AG_04-Nov-2015_bis_03-Nov-2018.pdf

PS C:\Temp\test>
```

Comment: Umm... does `03-Nov-2018` look like it'd be matching the format `yyyyMMdd` to you?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An approach with a regular expression to grep the date in a where-Object and
a single pipe should be more efficient:

```
# if the abbreviated month names compply with the current culture
$CI = Get-Culture

# or a selected deviating culture
#$CI = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo("de-DE")

$RE = "_bis_(\d{2}-("+($CI.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames -ne '' -join '|')+")-20\d{2})"

Get-ChildItem | Where-Object {$_.Name -match $RE -and 
    ([datetime]::ParseExact($Matches[1],"dd-MMM-yyyy",$CI) -lt [datetime]::now)}|
        Move-Item -Destination "C:\temp\test\copy\" -WhatIf
```

If the output looks OK remove the `-WhatIf`

To better explain what `$CI` for culture information returns,

On my German locale

```
> $CI = Get-Culture
> $CI.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames -ne '' -join '|'
Jan|Feb|Mrz|Apr|Mai|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Okt|Nov|Dez
```

---

```
> $CI = New-Object system.globalization.cultureinfo("en-US")
> $CI.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames -ne '' -join '|'
Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec
> $RE = "_bis_(\d{2}-("+($CI.DateTimeFormat.AbbreviatedMonthNames -ne '' -join '|')+")-20\d{2})"
> $RE
_bis_(\d{2}-(Jan|Feb|Mar|Apr|May|Jun|Jul|Aug|Sep|Oct|Nov|Dec)-20\d{2})
```

See the RegEx live on [regex101.com](https://regex101.com/r/OFXRDU/1)

Answer (score 0):

As @AnsgarWiechers pointed out, you are not using the correct date format.

### MWE

```
$a = dir c:\temp\test
$a | foreach {
    $file = $_.Name;
    $full = $_.FullName

    switch -wildcard ($file) {
        "*bis_*" {
            $file
            [string]$date = ($file.Split("_"))[2]
            $date
            $datetime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($date, "dd-MMM-yyyy", $null)
            $datetime
            if ($datetime -lt (Get-Date)) {
                Move-Item $full "C:\temp\test\copy\"
            }
        }
    } #end switch
} #end foreach
```

### Edit

It appears that all of your files do not follow the same structure. I take it that you should use the dat after `bis_` based on the two provided examples:

> - TSE_M001340_04-Nov-2015_bis_03-Nov-2018.pdf
> - file_test_bis_23-APR-2021.pdf

Here is the updated code:

```
$a = dir c:\temp\test
$a | foreach {
    $file = $_.BaseName;
    $full = $_.FullName
    $split = "bis_"

    switch -wildcard ($file) {
        "*$split*" {
            $file
            [string]$date = ($file.Split($split))[1]
            $date
            $datetime = [DateTime]::ParseExact($date, "dd-MMM-yyyy", $null)
            $datetime
            if ($datetime -lt (Get-Date)) {
                Move-Item $full "C:\temp\test\copy\"
            }
        }
    } #end switch
} #end foreach
```

Comment: i only need to look for the name after "bis_XXX" so that's why my test file looks different the a original one.